# Same or different result in query

Tags: mysql

I've 1 query written in our legacy system. (using MySQL 5.5)
Now, with growing data - the below mentioned query taking huge time. 
In our system, we've somewhat 200,00,00,000 (2 billion rows) approx 650 GB of data.
Table is partitioned with respect to every day. (which means above query is fetching data from 30 partitions).

Allocate 16GB to innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Query-1

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l FROM TEST WHERE START_TIME between '2013-11-14 00:00:01' and '2013-12-14 23:59:59'  ORDER BY START_TIME DESC) as TEST_DATA LIMIT 10000;
```

Above Query => Means selecting all the columns for all the data between 1 month and performing sorting and at last show 10000 records to end user.

Now, my doubt goes: Query-2

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l FROM TEST WHERE START_TIME between '2013-11-14 00:00:01' and '2013-12-14 23:59:59'  ORDER BY START_TIME DESC limit 10000;
```

Above Query => selecting all the columns from 1 month of data and perform sorting and display the result as soon as 10000 records sorted. (No sorting and buffering of all records).

With Query-1 and Query-2 -> Does these 2 queries will display different result set? Or same?

Because in Query-1, we doing sorting on all records and then display 10k 
whereas in Query-2, we doing display 10k sorted records.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to test this on a small subset of your data. Use `EXPLAIN` to find out what MySQL is doing.  I think you'll probably get the same results for both queries.

Comment: lets consider:
> create table test (id,name) with id as PK. Insert 10 records: (1,'gaga'),... (10,'kaka');

Now: 
Select * from test where id>2 order by id desc limit 2;

Select * from (select * from test where id>2 order by id desc) as t limit 2;

Now,lets say on disk data stored like:
1,'gaga' - block 1
.
10,'kaka' - block 10

Now, while selecting:
Query-1 may give: (bcoz query 1 will stop as soon as it gets the desired result set of 2 rows whose id>2, Or it does the sorting of whole result set first)
4,'lala' - block 4
3,'sasa' - block 3

query-2:
10,'kaka' - block 10
9,'yaya' - block 9